# SQLGrammarException. Unknown column name in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database where I have countries table. The countries table has following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `idCountry` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `countryCode` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `countryName` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCountry`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=252 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a hibernate Pojo which is configured properly in hibernate configuration file. The pojo looks like this

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    public String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
    return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The database is already populated with list of all the countries and corresponding values. However when I try to get a contry from the table using the following code

```
SessionFactory sf = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Country c = (Country) session.get(Country.class, 105);
    return c;
```

I am getting the following exception

```
[org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'country0_.id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: If you created this table by yourself you may consider reading this naming conventions for SQL: https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public int id;

@Column(name = "code")
public String code;

@Column(name = "name")
public String name;
```

To this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "idCountry")
public int id;

@Column(name = "countryCode")
public String code;

@Column(name = "countryName")
public String name;
```

Comment: It wasnt working when I kept the names as is. But now it does. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No, he should use the names provided in his model class. These are much better than the current column names.

Comment: does that mean I can not use different names? other than the one specified in the sql structure?

Comment: @RJadhav you can have different names for your attributes, and use the `@Column` annotation to identify it otherwise Hibernate would not have a way to tell which is for what. The normal way is to have the attributes with the same names. It normally happens when you have legacy tables to map.